# ResponseDelivery Implementations

Tags: android-volley

I would like to implement a common error handler that will handle errors of a particular status code. I would like every request put on the queue to have the same behavior. One scenario would be upon a 401. When a 401 status is received, I would like to show a login dialog and then replay the original request without the activity that launched that request having to know anything about it.
   I was looking at implementing a custom ResponseDelivery that is almost identical to the ExecutorDelivery. However when I went to do this, I discovered that the Request.finish method is package private. Is there a better way to implement this kind of behavior with volley? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start from following:

```java
public abstract class BaseRequest<T extends ErrorResponse> extends Request<T> {
    @Override
    protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        jsonString = new String(response.data);
        T parsedResponse = null;
        try {
            parsedResponse = parseJson(jsonString);
            // this is where you can handle any type of common errors from server
            if (parsedResponse != null && parsedResponse.getErrorCode() == 401) {
                return Response.error(new SessionExpiredError(parsedResponse.getErrorMessage()));
            }
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            Ln.e(e, "JsonSyntaxException");
            Ln.e(jsonString);
            return Response.error(new VolleyError(e));
        }

        return Response.success(parsedResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
}

  public class ErrorStatusResponse {
    private int errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    ...
}
```

All your requests extending BaseRequest will be checked against errors you specify before result is delivered.

Moving on, you cannot start any activity or present dialog without context (and you don't want to pass `Context` to ResponseDelivery. So you could create BaseActivity for this purpose:

```java
public abstract class BaseActionBarActivity
        extends ActionBarActivity
        implements Response.ErrorListener {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      // if your ChildActivitiy wants to override this method, make sure to call super.onErrorResponse 
      if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
        noConnection();
      } else if (error instanceof SessionExpiredError) {
        sessionExpired(); // startForResult some LoginActivity here
      } else {
        Ln.e(error);
      }
    }
}
```

In order to fire previous request again, I'd do smth like this:

```java
// ChildActivity
public void fireRequest() {
  api.getMyItemsFromServer();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == SUBACTIVITY_SESSION_EXPIRED) {
    api.getMyItemsFromServer();
  }
}
```

or you could save last unsuccessful request in `BaseActivity` and handle it in its `onActivityResult()`